# Java how to display ranges of records that are read

Tags: java, loops

So in my application I am trying to iterate through my rs records. I want to be able to print out a ranch of records at a time so like if I have 100 records and records 3, 12-15 and 40-60 are missing, I want it to display the records that was read. So I can know that the other records are missing/skipped. I have posted a more completed code here [Java JDBC display first 500 records at a time, commit, than display the next 500 records and etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302371/java-jdbc-display-first-500-records-at-a-time-commit-than-display-the-next-500/31338674?noredirect=1#comment50750915_31338674)

`updated records 1-2
updated records 4-11
updated records 13-39
updated records 61-100`

```
 try {
             int rowCount = 0;   
           while (rs.next()) {


                 String ingressflag = rs.getString("ingress_flag");     
                 String egressflag = rs.getString("egress_flag");       
                 String ceingressflag = rs.getString("ce_ingress_flag"); 
                 String ceegressflag = rs.getString("ce_egress_flag");  
                 int profileid = rs.getInt("profile_id");               

                preparedStatement.setString(1, ingressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, egressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, ceingressflag);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, ceegressflag);
                preparedStatement.setInt(5, profileid);

                preparedStatement.addBatch();
                rowCount++;
               // System.out.println("profileid updated : " + profileid     +  " timestamp " +  new java.util.Date()  + "\n");

           }
```

Comment: So, you mean to say that `profile_id` is missing and not records missing?

Comment: `profile_id` is the range between 1-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find which `profile_id` is missing you could try to declare a variable of type `int` say `expectedId` and initialise to the starting `profile_id` of the table in your case 1. Then in the while loop check whether the `profile_id` returned is equal to the `expectedId` if not print out the message and finally increment the `expectedId` by 1 as Illustrated below.

```
int expectedId = 1;
while (rs.next()) {
    //All your code
    if(expectedId != profileid){
       System.out.println ("Profile id "+expectedId+" to "+(profileid-1)+" missing.";
       expectedId = profileid;
    }
    expectedId++;
}
```

Here whenever the sequence is missing it will give an output stating the id from which to which are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array of booleans that is the same size as the number of records your have. Then set each corresponding value to `True` if and only if that record was updated.

Then from this array you can give output in the form you suggested by simply looping through the array with something like:

```
int first;
int last = 0;
while(!records[last]) //skip through records 1-x that are missing
    last++;
first = last+1;

for(int i = last; i < numRecords; i++){
    if(records[i]) //keep going if record there
        last++;
    else{ //otherwise print out previous "streak" and start anew
        if(first == last) //streak of 1
            System.out.println("updated record " + first);
        else //streak of >1
            System.out.println("updated records " + first + "-" + last);
        while(!records[i]) //skip over entire missing section
            i++;
        first = i+1; //new first is next valid value
        last = first;
    }
}

if(records[numRecords-1])//if end reached without printing last streak
    System.out.println("updated records " + first + "-" + last); //print it now
```

Comment: `numRecords` in your example would be my total number of records in this case `100`, and your `records` variable would be my `rowCount`

Comment: @yescobar1 well this is just some generic code. I think I've accounted for most cases of missing records. Let me know if this is something that would work for you.